# code -32000 message: account is locked

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, wallets, accounts

I am trying to withdraw some coins from my wallet (as I have done several times prior) but this time I am prompted with the error:

```
 {0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})
{
  code: -32000,
  message: "account is locked"
}
```

I've tried unlocking the account using the `--unlock` command

```
geth --unlock "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

but unfortunately it did not fix the issue.

Comment: What was the actual error of `geth --unlock` ?

Comment: Okay, so I never could unlock my account within GETH or Console and truthfully sent me into a small panic mode (and that's no where anyone wants to be). Thankfully coping my keystore file to my Windows PC, UI Wallet, I was able to move my coins. No more worries thank God but very strange and I would curious to know how this happened.

Answer (score 2):

You have to send the index of the account address on eth.accounts to unlock it and the path to the password file:

Like:

```
geth --unlock=0 --password="./password-file-path"
```

This will unlock the first address on eth.accounts and use the content on the file as password.