# Account is locked. How to unlock it using json-rpc?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, accounts, testnets

When trying to send a transaction through json-rpc interface on a geth node (version 1.4.10-stable-5f55d95a, running on testnet) using `eth_sendTransaction` I got this error message:

> -32000 [message] => account is locked

I have tried to unlock the account using the following command:

```
geth --testnet --exec "personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], password, 3600)" attach true http://localhost:8545
```

But I get another error:

> Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: invalid endpoint

Trying to unlock as explained in [how to unlock the account with geth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/how-to-unlock-the-account-with-geth)

```
geth --testnet --unlock 0x3b877e80b... --password password
```

throws this error too:

> Fatal: Could not open database: resource temporarily unavailable

Another option to unlock account according to previous URL is using the Geth interactive Javascript console. But how do I launch such console?

I've seen someone is having same problem on [code -32000 message: account is locked](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/code-32000-message-account-is-locked) but any command of the kind

```
geth --unlock
```

is not working on my geth node.

Is it possible to unlock accounts directly through json-rpc interface anyhow?

Why geth is not allowing me to unlock my ethereum account? Why "invalid endpoint"?

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7196/is-it-possible-to-unlock-a-geth-wallet-through-json-rpc

Comment: Are both your geth commands run from the same computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The command with `attach` should be like:

```
$ geth --testnet --exec "personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], \"password\", 3600)" attach http://localhost:8545
```

Make sure that you have included `personal` in your `--rpcapi "eth,web3,personal"` in the first Geth you launched.

2. The command with `unlock` should be used as part of the *first* Geth launch:

   - Have a `password.txt` file that contains as many lines as there are accounts to unlock. Each line with `password` without the `"`.
   - Then add `--unlock "0x3b877e80b..." --password password.txt` to your Geth command line.
3. Beside that, to launch Geth with a console, just add `console` at the end. So, when you are in the Geth console, you can type:

```
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])
// Or
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "password")
// Or
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "password", 3600)
```

Edit:

At your own risk, because the call carries the password in clear, the direct call to unlock via RPC is:

```
$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["0x7642b...", "password", 3600],"id":67}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":67,"result":true}
```

Comment: Given that exporting `personal` over `rpc` opens up a node to exploits shouldn't they be attaching through `ipc` instead, e.g. `geth --testnet --exec "personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], \"password\", 3600)" attach ~/<datadir>/geth.ipc`?

Comment: I agree 100%. I just asked if both Geth are on the same computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using command line call to geth as you described worked like a charm. Nevertheless, I wonder if this unlock action could be also possible through json-rpc protocol, avoinding admin intervention on command line.

Comment: I added it in the answer, but be careful, the password is travelling in the clear.

Comment: is there way for unlock account using private key not using password @XavierLeprêtreB9lab

Comment: @YogeshKarodiya A locked account here means a locked private key.

Comment: @XavierLeprêtreB9lab please answer this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29904/how-to-unlockaccount-account-using-private-key-instead-of-password question