# Is it faster to use "geth --unlock" than "personal.unlockAccount"?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

I have a script that I run with `geth attach`, and then I use:

```
primary = eth.accounts[0];
personal.unlockAccount(primary, "password");
```

like I saw in [the example script](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/example_script.html).

Doing this in geth usually takes about one or two seconds. I learned there was [another way to unlock accounts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/how-to-unlock-the-account-with-geth). I was wondering if it was faster to unlock directly with `geth --unlock "0xaddress" --password "password" attach`. What does it do differently ?

How can I know if it unlocked successfully ? If I use a random address or password instead of the correct ones, `attach` still opens correctly.

EDIT: I found in the answer of [a duplicate question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8478/account-is-locked-how-to-unlock-it-using-json-rpc) that you can't use `--unlock` with `attach`, which wasn't in [the original answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4159/4832) (or at least not clearly).

Geth attach "opens correctly" because it ignores those flags. You can run `geth --unlock "0xaddress" --password "password" attach` or `geth --password --testnet --testnet attach` and it will open like `geth attach` (flag order seems to be important sometimes though, you can't use `password` after `testnet` or it ignores `attach`).

Answer (score 3):

`--unlock` also takes a second, no benefit here. On the other hand, not showing your password on the command line is a net benefit. Yes, make it `--password password_file.txt` instead of plain password in the command.

If it failed to decrypt, then Geth will exit with error code `1`:

```
$ geth --unlock "0" --password password_file.txt
...
Fatal: Failed to unlock account 0 (could not decrypt key with given passphrase)
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thanks. Does `--password` always expect a file path ? If I have my password in a variable, could `--password $password` work ? I can't get it to work. My primary account is unlocked automatically for some reason, and I can't unlock my second with `--unlock`

Comment: just an information about --password when you use it with plain text password keep in mind your password will be shown in the log.

Comment: @Xavier what do you mean by net benefit?

Comment: @BadrBellaj Can I even use it with plain password ? How does geth know ?

Comment: I never tried passing the password plainly in the command line. But, if it were possible, having a password just accessible in the history of my shell is a liability. Not having it in the history is a net benefit.

Comment: It only gets worse doing it over RPC :D