# Is there an API for json rpc transactions and signing?

Tags: rpc

I've been looking at a lot of node host providers like infura and they don't allow for ethereum json rpc signing or transactions for security reasons (private key handling). I thought that I could just look up an api to allow me to do this, but haven't found any.

My goal is to do transactions on the ropsten network ONLY through xml rpc requests (as I am working in a limited environment that doesn't allow for library importations) and was wondering if there is a solution or api that would help.

Answer (score 1):

[Geth's JSON-RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) supports the ability to send/sign transactions. You will need to explicitly allow access to an unlocked account. If you don't care about security, you can allow `personal` via RPC and unlock the test account that way. See [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8478/account-is-locked-how-to-unlock-it-using-json-rpc) on keeping insecure geth accounts.

For signing and sending transactions, see [eth_sign](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign) and [eth_sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction).